# urlencode() encode part of variable in query to ¬

Tags: php, urlencode

I've got this odd behaviour where `&notify_url=xxx` in a URL turns into `&¬ify_url=xxx`?

How can I stop this from happening?

The value strings are already url encoded.

Thanks in advance.

// edit:
complete url: https://domain.com/eng/process?merchant_id=xxx&merchant_key=xxx&return_url=http%3A%2F%2FdomainX.com%2Fdev%2Fxxx%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D62%26Itemid%3D259%26payment_success%3D1&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2FdomainX.com%2Fdev%2Fsacnasp%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D62%26Itemid%3D259%26payment_success%3D-1¬ify_url=http%3A%2F%2Flightside.co.za%2Fdev%2Fsacnasp%2Fpayfast%2Fitn.php&name_first=YYYY&email_address=xxx%40domainX.com&m_payment_id=YYYY_857&amount=4500.00&item_name=YYYY+Application+fee&email_confirmation=1&confirmation_address=yyyy%40domainX.com

// code to create url:

```
$data = array(
    // Merchant details
    'merchant_id' => $form->data['merchant_id'],
    'merchant_key' => $form->data['merchant_key'],
    'return_url' => $form->data['return_url'],
    'cancel_url' => $form->data['cancel_url'],
    'notify_url' => $form->data['notify_url'],
    'name_first' => $form->data['name_first'],
    'email_address' => $form->data['email_address'],
    'm_payment_id' => $form->data['m_payment_id'],
    'amount' => $form->data['amount'],
    'item_name' => $form->data['item_name'],
    'email_confirmation' => $form->data['email_confirmation'],
    'confirmation_address' => $form->data['confirmation_address'],
);

// Create GET string
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    if (!empty($val)) {
        $pfOutput .= $key . '=' . urlencode(trim($val)) . '&';
    }
}
// Remove last ampersand
$getString = substr($pfOutput, 0, -1);
```

Comment: Which charset are you using ?

Comment: Can you share some code? I'm not seeing this locally. `urlencode('&notify_url=xxx') => %26notify_url%3Dxxx

Comment: Sounds like a simple encoding issue. Check the encoding for your files and server.

Comment: You can also check possibility with entitydecode('&notify_url=xxx')

Comment: it turn &not to '&¬' this is for "not",simple way to change variable name.

Comment: I can't change the variable name as I'm posting to an external payment gateway

Comment: I assume the charset is UTF-8